# EXTJS 5 - couldn't read the addCls() method

Tags: css, extjs5

I changed extjs 4.2.4 to 5.0.0 and It couldn't read the second addCls() method in same "constructor: function". Any idea?

```
    Ext.define('GMIS.view.charts.pie.BasicPie', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
            storeValue: null, //'BankerDataStoreChr'
            widthValue: null,
            heightValue: null,      
            titleValue : null,
            identifier: null,
            styleValue : null,
            styleValue1 : null,
            chartValue : null,
            selBanker : null
        },
        storeValue: null,
        constructor: function(cfg){
            this.initConfig(cfg);
             this.callParent();
                 this.setTitle(this.getTitleValue());
                 this.addCls(this.getStyleValue());
                 this.addCls(this.getStyleValue1());
                this.setWidth(this.getWidthValue());
                this.setHeight(this.getHeightValue()+30);
      }
});
```

In the above coding, it could read the first addCls() method as "this.addCls(this.getStyleValue())" ,but i Couldn't read the second addCls() method as "this.addCls(this.getStyleValue1())"

in the above,this.getStyleValue() returns the "chart-item-body" and this.getStyleValue1() returns the "gmis-panel-class"

css:

```
.chart-item-body {
     background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.gmis-panel-class .x-panel-body {
     background-color: #fbfbfb;
     border-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.gmis-panel-class .x-panel-header-text {
     background-color: #fbfbfb;
     color: #000000;
     text-align: center;
     white-space: normal;

}

.gmis-panel-class .x-panel-header-inner .x-panel-header-text {
     white-space: normal;
     background-color: #fbfbfb;
     border-color: #d3d3d3;


}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: please create a js fiddle with the minimal part of the code in order to reproduce the error. thanks